# _all field in match phrase prefix query

Tags: elasticsearch

My documents have field `product_code` containing string value like `pc00XXa` where `X` is replaced by some digit 1..9. I'm expecting result of 9 documents with this phrase prefix query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "pc001",
        "type": "phrase_prefix"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... but the result is empty. Using `product_code` instead of `_all`, I get the expected 9 documents.

Using prefix query instead of phrase prefix query seems to work as expected with both `_all` and `product_code` fields. Following query gives me 9 documents:

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "_all": {
        "value": "pc001"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Elasticsearch documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-match-query.html#_match_phrase_prefix) says "The match_phrase_prefix is the same as match_phrase, except that it allows for prefix matches on the last term in the text". In my case I have only one term in the query so I would expect it to work as a prefix.

How exactly does phrase prefix query differ from prefix query when the query contains single term? And why the use of `_all` gives me fewer results than specifying the field name explicitly?

Comment: What type of field is `product_code` and what analyzer is being used for it?

Comment: @AndreiStefan It's string field with default analyzer (= standard analyzer?)

Comment: Works for me. There must be something else going on with either your mapping or your data.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have a similar issue where a phrase prefix query does not return any results if the field "_all" is used.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi Not really a solution but I started using multi match query and specify every field explicitly.

Comment: I ran into this issue after upgrading elasticsearch from 1.7 to 2.4. Maybe it's version dependent?

Comment: Regarding `multi_match_query`: You can specify wildcards for `fields` (like `"fields": ["*"]` or `"fields": ["*_included_in_all"]`).

Comment: N.B.: We used `"match": {"_all": {"type": "phrase_prefix", …}}` successfully with elasticsearch 1.7.

Comment: Update: seems like `multi_match_query` with `"fields": ["*"]` does not work while `"fields": ["*blabla"]` does.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Are you able to reproduce this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199332/multi-match-phrase-prefix-query-using-all