# `multi_match` `phrase_prefix` query using `_all`

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue boiling down to this unexpected behavior:

I'm using a test index with these contents:

```
DELETE /test_index?ignore_unavailable=true

POST /test_index/content/1
{
  "name": "lorem"
}
```

Now I cannot do a `multi_match` `phrase_prefix` query using `_all`, searching for e.g. `lore`.

That is, the following query yields 0 results:

```
POST /test_index/content/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "lore",
      "fields": [
        "_all"
      ],
      "type": "phrase_prefix"
    }
  }
}
```

Changing the `query` to `lorem` (the complete term), yields the expected document.

Changing the query to match the `name` field specifically, also works.

I've tried this on ES 2.3.1. Could anyone confirm, explain, or give a solution?

Comment: not sure what is different in 2.1 but I tried this in 5.0 and it works.

Comment: Have you tried to use `match_phrase_prefix` instead instead of `multi_match`?

Comment: @Val The thing is that I want to be able to use multiple fields

Comment: Ok, that wasn't obvious from your example.

Comment: @root545, this works OOTB in ES 5.1. If you want the accepted answer, you can add another or edit your existing one.

Comment: @BjörnAliGöransson I have edited the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work OOTB in ES 5.1.

Comment: Alas, this does not work in my ES2.3.1. Will try with ES5.1 now to see if it works OOTB, as you  said.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in ES 2.3.

See: [multi_match with type phrase_prefix query doesn't return all the results on the field _all](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20470)